# Authorize Policy attribute always returns 403 forbidden using .net core Identity and JwtBearerAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, claims-based-identity

Following [this guide](https://auth0.com/blog/asp-dot-net-core-authentication-tutorial/) I was able to get authentication working using

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
```

Now I'm trying to secure my api endpoints with either roles, or claims. I've tried both with the same result (403)

Using just `[Authorize]` works fine.

My code currently looks something like this:

> Controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireUserRole")]
// Also tried [Authorize(Roles="User")]
public string Get()
{   
  return "YO";
}
```

> Startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
services.Configure<JWTSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings"));
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
        options.AddPolicy("RequireUserRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));
});
```

...

```
app.UseIdentity();

var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:SecretKey").Value;
var issuer = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Issuer").Value;
var audience = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings:Audience").Value;
var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

                // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = issuer,

                // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = audience,

                ValidateLifetime = true
        }
});

app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

and when I create the user I assign it to the role "User"

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
```

The role relationship is being created successfully, but the validation for the role when hitting the endpoint is failing.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Something notable for me was that `.RequrieClaim("role", "admin")` did not work and `.RequireRole("admin")` did so thanks for giving me that idea to try

Comment: I had to change the role claim type like so for Azure applicaiton authorization:  options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is in this [mdsn blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/):

> Authorizing based on roles is available out-of-the-box with ASP.NET
>   Identity. As long as the bearer token used for authentication contains
>   a roles element, ASP.NET Core’s JWT bearer authentication middleware
>   will use that data to populate roles for the user.
>
> So, a roles-based authorization attribute (like [Authorize(Roles =
>   "Manager,Administrator")] to limit access to managers and admins) can
>   be added to APIs and work immediately.

So I added an element to my access token object called roles:

```
private string GetAccessToken(string userRole)
{
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ...
        { "roles", userRole } 
    };
    return GetToken(payload);
}
```

Comment: I think that would be a bad practice in systems, where you may change user roles, and the user logged in once before and has long expiry time.

Answer (score 0):

I read that msdn post and added in startup:

```
   internal class HasRoleRequerementAuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasRoleRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasRoleRequirement requirement)
    { 

        if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId))
            if (context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Typ).Value == requirement.RoleName)
                context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
}    
internal class HasRoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public readonly string RoleName;

    public HasRoleRequirement(string roleName)
    {
        RoleName = roleName;
    }
}
```

Then added policy:

```
       opt.AddPolicy("Test", builder =>
            {
                builder.Requirements.Add(new HasRoleRequirement("User"));
            });
```

My token is generated like this:

```
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.Uid),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Typ, type.ToString())
        };


        var creds = new SigningCredentials(_key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var tokenDesc = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDesc);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

And then I can use policy Auth header:

```
    [HttpGet("TestAuth")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Test")]
    public IActionResult TestAuth()
    {
        return new OkResult();
    }
```